# Convergence of Fourier series on the $d$-dimensional torus for $C^k$-functions.

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

According to Theorem 16 in [this document](https://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/schick/teach/jvnfour1.pdf), if $f \in C^{k + \lceil\frac{d+1}{2}\rceil}(\mathbb{T}^d, \mathbb{C})$ then 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \hat{f}(k)e^{i \langle k, x \rangle},
$$
in the $C^k(\mathbb{T}^d, \mathbb{C})$ norm.

Does anyone know of a more permanent reference for this fact? Specifically, something that isn't just hosted on the authors website, such as a book or paper.

Comment: You have to use some version of the Dirichlet criteria that says that the Fourier series of Lipschitz functions converge uniformly. Extend it to $d$ dimensions and add $m$ derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am aware of a proof and just need to a reference for a paper - something permanent would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the author of the lecture notes in my original post, Oliver Bräunling, and he rightly directed me to Proposition 5.6 and Theorem 5.7 in the book "Elliptic operators, topology and asymptotic methods" by John Roe. As Oliver pointed out, the result is a corollary of the proof of the Sobolev embedding theorem on the $d$-dimensional torus.